# Display selected document from input type: file

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

**Html**

```
<input type="file" accept=".docx" type="file" id="fileUpload" onchange="setFile()" />
```

**Javascript**

`const setFile = () => { console.log(document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0])}`

And I'm trying to get the selected file to display in the console but to no avail. Pls how can I fix this?

Here is the sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/embed/fancy-river-9dn69?codemirror=1

Comment: what do you want to be displayed? is it the name?

Comment: The file name and its other properties

Comment: Your code is displaying information on the console.

Comment: @Gass it doesn't display

Answer (score 1):

Just reference the name property and you'll have what you're looking for.

```js
const setFile = () => { 
    console.log(document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0].name)
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept=".docx" type="file" id="fileUpload" onchange="setFile()" />
```

Other properties such as lastModified, lastModifiedDate, type and others are also available on it so just refer the onces you'll like to display.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting same outcome. Nothing is being displayed in the console

Answer (score 0):

"setFile()" treated as string not function call ,So to call SetFile() , You need to Call it , So use `onChange={setFile()}` , if you are working in react

```
const setFile = () => { 
    console.log(document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0].name)
}
```

```
<input type="file" accept=".docx" type="file" id="fileUpload" onchange={setFile()} />
```

Comment: Its just html and javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your code is indeed extracting the info of the object file. Here you can see been rendered inside `<body>`

```js
const setFile = () => { 
  const fileObject = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0]; 
  document.getElementById('title').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('one').append('Name: ' + fileObject.name)
  document.getElementById('two').append('Last Modified: ' + fileObject.lastModified)
  document.getElementById('three').append('Last Modified Date: ' + fileObject.lastModifiedDate)
  document.getElementById('four').append('Size: ' + fileObject.size)
  document.getElementById('five').append('Type: ' + fileObject.type)
}
```

```css
div{margin:10px 0}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept=".docx" type="file" id="fileUpload" onchange="setFile()" />
<h1 id="title" style="display:none">File Info</h1>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>
```

Comment: Still not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Using a Label tag instead of button tag to trigger the file input helped resolve the issue. Although i can't understand why.